# How to get the parent category's thumbnail image of the product? ifthe product has no image at all in magento 1.9.2.1

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category, product-images

I have a problem since I'm new to magento.

I have a product that has no product placeholder. I want that if the product has no image placeholder it will automatically use it's parent category image as placeholder.

Comment: what u mean by `parent category'?

Comment: I mean it will use the parent category's thumbnail image if the product has no thumbnail image. or placeholder.